# conditionalPanel condition contained in a list

Tags: r, shiny

So, I have a checkboxgroupButtons where the user can select one or more options

```
checkboxGroupButtons("id","select options",
                             choices = c( "A","B","C" )
                             ,selected = "A"
                            , checkIcon = list(yes = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"))
                             , direction = "vertical"
                 )
```

Then I want a conditional panel, but I want it such that the action depends if user selects "A" or (inclusive) "B". Already tried &&. Tried || but it doesn't logically accepts the inclusion. also tried
input.id.values, but it triggers even if I select "A" and "C".

```
conditionalPanel( condition = "input.id=='A' || input.id=='B'" , helpText("something") )
```

How can I set a condition is :  "input.id"  contained in the list ("A","B")

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you want the conditional panel to trigger if you select A or B, but then complain that it triggers when you select A and C.  That seems to satisfy your logic: A and C includes A.  Or do you mean "only A" or "only B"?  If so, would a condition on the length of `input.id` help?  As an aside, personally, I think `shinyFeedback' or `shinyhelper` are easier and more elgant ways of displaying help text.

Comment: @Limey only A or (inclusive) B
I mean
selected {A}, selected {B}, selected {A,B} are included in {A,B}, so it triggers the action
selected {A,C}, are not included in {A,B}, so it won't trigger the action

Comment: Then I think something similar to `conditionalPanel( condition = "(input.id=='A' || input.id=='B') & input.id != 'C'" , helpText("something") )` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but could you try

```
input.id.every(i => i === 'A' || i === 'B')
```

Or, if the browser you use does not support `=>`:

```
input.id.every(function(i){return i==='A' || i==='B';})
```

Comment: @Mikael I've just checked and this JavaScript code is valid. I don't see why it would not work.